# Как получить ширину и высоту окна зная его Handle?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Как получить ширину и высоту окна зная его Handle?
Использую Delphi XE7.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `GetWindowRect()` из WinAPI.